# Javascript regex for a comma seperated sequence of numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex in javascript for a pattern. This pattern looks like followed:

**(any number followed by a comma) --> 1..5 times followed optionally by any number**

**some valid examples:**

```
1002
1001,1002,1003,21313,3333
912393,4951131313,92812,3131,43434,13123
```

**some invalid examples:**

```
a
some_string1, ,somestring2,32232
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
100,200,300,
```

As you can see by the given examples there is the following rule:

**number->comma->number => valid**

**number => valid**

**number->comma => invalid**

**anything else than a number => invalid**

**more than six numbers => invalid**

I already tried to find a solution by myself but without any luck.

I created this here:

```
/(^d+,){1,5}d?$/
```

But unfortunately it does not work. By the way: I'm not really into regular expression, I'm gonna try to practice it in the future. ;-)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Add some examples of valid and invalid strings

Comment: Post some valid and invalid matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were so close

```
/^(\d+,){1,5}\d*$/
 ^ ^         ^ ^
 1 2         3 4
```

1. the beginning of line needs to be outside the parenthesis
2. the d should be \d
3. the d should be \d
4. ? = 0 or 1, * = 0 or more (if the last number can only be a single digit, then use ? like you did

the above matches one wrong pattern, `1,2,3,4,5,` would match!!

```
/^(\d+,|){1,4}\d+(,\d+|)$/
```

that's better (it works 100%, but probably not the optimal solution)

Comment: this is exactly that what i was looking for... thank you

Answer (score 3):

you can also use

```
^(\d*?,.){1,5}$
```

may it works!